# How have others implemented complex filtering in a RESTful API?

Tags: python, rest, filtering

I am building a RESTful API which requires advanced filtering for a number of its resources. I need to support almost everything you can do in a SQL where clause. How have others implemented this functionality in their APIs?

The more research I do the more it looks like I need to either find a parser for an already defined grammar like SQL or RQL or write my own that is drastically simplified. I am working in Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is the OData standard. OData is a REST+ATOM combination that includes an in-URL query language.

Here is an example of an OData query call on a webservice:

```
http://services.odata.org/OData.svc/Category(1)/Products?$top=25&$orderby=name
```

This (fictional) query searches for the top 25 products in category 1 ordered by name from the OData.svc webservice.

Check out http://www.odata.org/ for more on OData.

There are implementations for Python available but I'm not sure how advanced they are at this stage. Check out http://code.google.com/p/odata-py and https://bitbucket.org/dowski/myohdata/src.